# Merge pandas datasets with different indices and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm fairly sure I'm missing a version of this question elsewhere on the site, but cannot for the life of me find it. I can't be the first person to have this issue.

In essence, I'm looking for a function that would merge pandas Dataframes in the equivalent way that a nested version of dict.merge would. If A and B are dictionaries of dictionaries, then we'd get `C = {k: A.get(k, {}) | B.get(k, {}) for k in set().union(*[A, B])}`

Concretely, I have two Pandas datasets A and B, with different sets of indices and columns (but not necessarily disjoint).

I would like a dataset C, whose indices are the union of A and B's indices and whose columns are the union of A and B's columns. The values are taken from B, if B has a non-NaN value for that particular index/column, otherwise it uses A.

I want a function `SuperMerge`: `C = A.SuperMerge(B)`. Assume the dataframes have some method `df.get(i, c, default=pd.NA)` that returns `df[i, c]` if it exists otherwise it returns `default`.

`SuperMerge` works like this:

`C[i,c] = B.get([i, c]) if not B.get([i, c]).isna() else A.get([i, c])`

Based on the lack of questions that address this, and the lack of Pandas functionality, I assume this is extremely rare use-case, but it's effectively how Python's dict update works: the updated dictionary now has the union of keys from both dicts, taking values from the right dict if available else it takes the one from the left dict.

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b'], 'col2': [1, 2], 'col4': ['col4_x', 'col4_y']}, index=['x', 'y'])

  col1  col2    col4
x    a     1  col4_x
y    b     2  col4_y
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['ALT', 'c'], 'col3': ['ONE', 'THREE'], 'col4': [pd.NA, 'col4_z']}, index=['x', 'z'])

  col1   col3    col4
x  ALT    ONE    <NA>
z    c  THREE  col4_z
```

```
df1.SuperMerge(df2)

  col1  col2   col3    col4
x  ALT     1    ONE  col4_x
y    b     2   <NA>  col4_y
z    c  <NA>  THREE  col4_z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supermerge is essentially `combine_first`.

From the docs:

> Combine two DataFrame objects by filling null values in one DataFrame
> with non-null values from other DataFrame. The row and column indexes
> of the resulting DataFrame will be the union of the two. The resulting
> dataframe contains the 'first' dataframe values and overrides the
> second one values where both first.loc[index, col] and
> second.loc[index, col] are not missing values, upon calling
> first.combine_first(second).

```
df2.combine_first(df1)
```

---

```
  col1  col2   col3    col4
x  ALT   1.0    ONE  col4_x
y    b   2.0    NaN  col4_y
z    c   NaN  THREE  col4_z
```

Comment: Wow really? I came across this function but after reading the start of the description thought it wasn't what I wanted: I thought inserted missing values but *didn't* override. Thanks!